# format text obtained from beautiful soup in python

Tags: python, html, regex, text

I used beautiful soup, and extracted some html that results in:

```
print(e)
<p class="top-half listing-results-marketed">
<small>
                                Listed on 
18th Jan 2017


                            by
                    </small><br/>
<span>xxx Agents</span>
```

I want to extract only the date and the estate agents.

To extract the agent, I used:

```
print(e.span.text)
xxx Agents
```

To extract the data, I use:

```
print(e.small.text.strip())
```

and ended up with:

```
Listed on 
18th Jan 2017


                            by
```

I am new to regex in python, and unsure how to extract only the date section. Any suggestions?

code used:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
url='https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/petts-wood/?page_size=100'

req=requests.get(url)
page_soup = soup(req.content,'html.parser')

containers = page_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'listing-results-wrapper'})

e=containers[0].find('p',{'class':'top-half listing-results-marketed'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

span_text = 'Listed on 18th Jan 2017                            by'
p = re.compile(r"[1-9]{1,2}[a-z]{2} [A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2} [0-9]{4}")
result = p.findall(span_text)

print(result)

#Output ['18th Jan 2017']
```

A site like [regexr](https://regexr.com) is awesome for learning regex.

Comment: Love the link now that I have played with it for a bit. Does python re follow perl exactly?

Answer (score 0):

To parse the date string to `datetime` object, you can use `re` module and `datetime.strptime` function ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)):

```
data = '''
<p class="top-half listing-results-marketed">
<small>
                                Listed on
18th Jan 2017


                            by
                    </small><br/>
<span>xxx Agents</span>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

time_data = re.findall(r'(\d+).*?\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+(\d{4})', soup.select_one('small').text)[0]
d = datetime.strptime(' '.join(time_data), '%d %b %Y')
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
2017-01-18 00:00:00
```